# How do I call a method from SessionSwitch event in windows application using c#?

Tags: c#, windows

How do I call a method from `SessionSwitch` event in windows application using c#? Any use of delegate is needed? Please help with a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += HandleSessionSwitch;

...

private static void HandleSessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Note: You should unsubscribe from this event when your application shuts down or memory leaks might result (as described in the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch.aspx)).

Comment: I'm not able to add the method call in that event. Getting an error message like this `Error 2 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestApp.Form1.AntivirusDefinitionCheck()' D:\Anish\TestApp\TestApp\Form1.cs 44 16 TestApp
`

Comment: @AnishV  For a non-static method you'll have to create an object first. But usually HandleSessionSwitch should be static.

Comment: @Anish: Make the handler static

Comment: Handler is already static. `static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventArgs e)` . The declaration is `            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);`

Comment: I have made it correct by changing the method to static. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` event. Note that the handler method must be `static`:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
[...]
static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

or, as always, a lambda expression will do:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += (sender, e) => { /* your code*/ };
```

Comment: Handler method is static. But still, I'm getting error like this. `Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TestApp.Form1.AntivirusDefinitionCheck()'`. :(

Comment: I have made it correct by changing the method to static. Thanks for your help.